# Text file in clearcase where the return is stripped

Tags: clearcase

I have a text file in clearcase (unix) When i open it on my windows clearcase client side the carriage returns are just fine.  However when i run the build and open after it has been checked in and labeled and packaged the carriage returns are removed.  If i open the file in unix the ^M is at the end of the file. I have tried removing them but they come right back.  I have tried dos 2 unix in a new file but same result. right now i am going to try and create a new view but sure what tmode.   Here is what i use and i have to make the view on unix.

```
cleartool mkview -tag view_name -tmode insert_cr -ncaexported ./view_name.vws
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `tmode`, see "[About text modes for views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_view_text_mode.htm)".
I really prefer "`transparent`": No line terminator processing is done.

Then, if you still see changes after build, you know this is not ClearCase doing, but potentially your build process that might change the eol style (end of line, with their carriage returns).